# Cygwin Control+D on Windows 7 doesn't give EOF signal

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, eof, getchar

I recently installed Cygwin64 and I am trying to run a C program which takes input from the keyboard using getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copies input to output

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

I have used stty -a to check what keyboard signals do what and EOF is correctly mapped to ctrl+D however it does nothing

[I have read that there may be a conflict with MinGW which I am also using](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/577)

My solution is switching to using the Cygwin terminal inside VS Code which instead uses windows keyboard signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still Ctrl+D. You have a typo in your code. You are not assigning the return value of `getchar` to `c`. Remove an equals sign.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't notice that.

Comment: Ctrl+D still does nothing though. None of my original code has that typo :)

Comment: Ctrl+D works for me with the example code you provided. I'm also using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: Can I ask if you are using MinGW?

Comment: I'm using gcc 7.3.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin). It's not MinGW.